# How can I get the checkbox value instead of selected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help, how can I get the checkbox value instead of the selected option.

```
$(function () {
    $('#addAsociado').click(function () {
        // This is the selected option, I want checkbox value
        return !$('#a_selectCta option:selected').appendTo('#contenedorLista');
    });

    $('#removeAsociado').click(
        function () {
            // This is the selected option, I want checkbox value
            return !$('#a_selectCta option:selected').remove().appendTo('#contenedorLista');
        });
});
```

Comment: $('#a_selectCta option:selected').val() ?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter no $('#a_selectCta option:selected') is a select option, and I want the value of a checkbox. I already tried $('#a_checkBox :checked').val(), but does not work!.

Comment: What do you mean by checkbox value?

Comment: Wait.. just noticed - yes, what checkbox value? Your code deals with select options no?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: Agreed. I downvoted because of this now.

Comment: checkbox value instead of the selected option... Maybe by selecting a checkbox instead of a select?

Comment: can you post your HTML?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I have a checkbox in my JSP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space from your checkbox selector (per the comments on the post, in the future, include what you've tried and failed on in the actual post):

```
$('#a_checkBox:checked').val()
```

Comment: This one is probably right, but the OP question is wrong... ;)

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear, it's just that 1: he didn't show any attempt at solving it on his own, and 2: he didn't show any information about the checkbox so we have no way of knowing how to select it (other than his comment, of course).

Comment: @paulinajr -- Please mark the answer as well if it solved everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for this:

```
 $('#a_checkBox').val()
```